# Impedir a duplicação no BD em função do loop FOR

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Estou criando um sistema de upload múltiplo de imagens. A função "move_uploaded_file" funciona direitinho. O problema é que incluí uma inserção $grav para o BD, e como pode ser visto no código, ele só seria enviado se as condições IF das imagens fosse respeitada. Só que quando o loop 'for' entra em execução, ele duplica essa inserção o número de vezes igual as imagens indexadas. Se forem 3, vai repetir a inserção 3 vezes, e assim por diante, e eu só queria 1 única inserção. Vi no Stack em inglês que há a possibilidade de usar ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE para evitar essa duplicação. Mas como eu faria isso?

```html
//INFO IMAGEM
  $file   = $_FILES['anexo'];
  $numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));
  
  //PASTA
  $folder  = 'docs';
  
  //REQUISITOS
  $permite  = array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/pdf');
  $maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
  
  //MENSAGENS
  $msg  = array();
  $errorMsg = array(
   1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
   2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
   3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
   4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
  );

    
 if($numFile <= 0)
   echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
  else{
   for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){

    $name  = $file['name'][$i];
    $type = $file['type'][$i];
    $size = $file['size'][$i];
    $error = $file['error'][$i];
    $tmp = $file['tmp_name'][$i];
    
    $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
    $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";
       
    if($error != 0) { $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error]; }
    else if(!in_array($type, $permite)) { $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!"; }
    else if($size > $maxSize) { $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB"; }
    
    else{

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)) {

//abaixo a inserção que está sendo duplicada
     
                $grav = "INSERT INTO propostaveic (tipseguro, marca, modelo, anofabric, modeloano, cambauto, veicblind, veicualien, veicudefic, kitgas, taxi, naresidenc, notrab, nocolegio, ceppernoite, veicupresta, veic85pc, ponthabilit, cidade, data, cnh, usuario) 
                VALUES ('$seguro1', '$seguro2', '$seguro3', '$seguro4', '$seguro5', '$seguro6', '$seguro7', '$seguro8', '$seguro9', '$seguro10', '$seguro11', '$seguro12', '$seguro13', '$seguro14', '$seguro15', '$seguro16', '$seguro17', '$seguro18', '$seguro19', '$seguro20', '$seguro21', '$usuario')";
                $exe_grav = mysqli_query($bd, $grav);
             

        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload Realizado com Sucesso!"; 
       
                 }

     else {
     $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";}
    
    }
    
    foreach($msg as $pop)
     echo $pop.'<br>';
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode apenas realizar uma contagem de imagens carregadas, e quando terminar o for verificar se todas as imagens foram carregas, utilizando um contador, exemplificando:

Coloque um contador de imagens carregadas antes do loop for

```
$imgscont = 0;
```

Para cada imagem carregada você incrementa um

```
$imgscont++; // dentro do loop
```

Após o loop for você faz a inserção no BD

```
if($imgscont == $numFile){
    // Iserção no BD aqui assim como a mensagem
}
```

Comment: Leano, o problema do 'break' é que ele irá brecar o loop após a primeira inserção, e a idéia não é essa, até porque eu preciso dele para mover os arquivos para a pasta um a um após a indexação.

Comment: Entendi agora o seu problema, vou postar outra resposta com um novo código

Comment: Excelente, Leano. Funcionou perfeitamente agora. Tenho certeza que vai ser útil pra muita gente. Obrigado!